# How to call a specific url from Django views?

Tags: python, django

I want to make a call to specific url pattern from Django Views.
The call should be inside first IF conditional and outside the inner if. Is the any function which provides redirection? Or something like redirect(map_vertical_crawl)? The code portion for
Django Views:

```
def add_vertical(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = VerticalForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        #I WANT TO CALL URL EXACTLY AT THIS POINT, INSIDE OUTER IF.

    verticals = Verticals.objects.all()

    return  render(request, 'cfman/add_vertical.html',
                   {'form': VerticalForm(),
                    'verticals': verticals}
                  )
```

Django URLS:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views, apps

urlpatterns = [

    #Generates Login Screen
    url(r'^$', views.LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),

    #Directs to manager view level 1
    url(r'^manager/$', views.verticals_view, name="manager"),

    #Directs to manager view level 2
    url(r'^manager/(?P<verticalid>\d+)/$', views.source_list, name='source_list'),

    #Add Vertical
    url(r'^verticals/add_vertical/$', views.add_vertical, name="add_vertical"),

    #Add Source
    url(r'^sources/add_source/$', views.add_source, name="add_source"),

    #Add Crawl Type
    url(r'^crawls/add_crawl/$', views.add_crawl, name="add_crawl"),

    #Map verticals and crawl types
    url(r'^vertical_crawl/$', views.map_vertical_crawl, name="map_vertical_crawl"),


]
```

I want to call the last url pattern , 'map_vertical_crawl' from views.

Comment: The program flow is correct.
The actual problem I am facing is, When I click on submit button, it just does POST, after post, i want to redirect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's built-in [redirect()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.redirect) accepts a view name as parameter, so just do:

```
redirect('cfman:map_vertical_crawl')
```

Comment: I want to call a specific URL pattern, named as map_vertical_crawl

Comment: I think redirect is used on **views to views functions** itself. I want to make a call to URL pattern.

Comment: @OmkarDeshpande Got it. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Can you just put example how to use it?

Comment: I tried 
from django.urls import reverse

reverse(map_vertical_crawl)

Comment: Sorry, my update was wrong. You can simply use `redirect('map_vertical_crawl')`. No need for `reverse`, as `redirect()` already acceps a view name as parameter. Please try this to make sure it works before I update the answer again.

Comment: I don't want to pass view name as parameter, I want to pass URL name as parameter.

Comment: That's what I meant. For example, to redirect to `url(r'^vertical_crawl/$', views.map_vertical_crawl, name="map_vertical_crawl"),`, you use `redirect('map_vertical_crawl')`, as `map_vertical_crawl` is the name. Isn't that what you need?

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /verticals/add_vertical/
Reverse for 'map_vertical_crawl' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: Check if you included this URLs file in another file, in which you might have defined a `namespace`. E.g. `url(r'^prefix/', include('myapp.urls', namespace='prefix'))`. If this is the case, you'd instead have to pass `prefix:map_vertical_crawl` to `redirect()`.

Comment: Thanks!     
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cfman:map_vertical_crawl'))
This worked!
Cfman was registered in namespace in base urls.py and map_vertical_crawl was in app's urls.py

Edit accordingly! :)

Comment: Nice, but note that `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cfman:map_vertical_crawl'))` is exactly the same as `redirect('cfman:map_vertical_crawl')` since Django 1.3 :) I will update the answer with the correct solution then.